# sqlite - where two records exist with a different value in certain column, only select certain record

Tags: sql, sqlite

if I have a very simple table:

```
id      outcome    position
--      -------    --------
1       TRUE          01
2       TRUE          01
2       FALSE         01
2       TRUE          02
```

where both the id and position can matches across multiple records; in that case, I would like to only select the FALSE outcome, i.e. when the same id and position appear in multiple record. for example id=1 only has 1 record, so TRUE or FALSE is fine here. The last record has id=2 (so same as 2nd and 3rd record), but the position=02, so it is fine to be TRUE or FALSE also. however because records 2 and 3 both share the same id and position, i only want to select the record with the false outcome. this should be the result:c

```
id      outcome    position
--      -------    --------
1       TRUE          01
2       FALSE         01
2       TRUE          02
```

How do I do this? I know I could create a table and then do something like

```
delete from mytable
where exists
(select a.* from mytable a
join mytable b
on a.id = b.id and a.position = b.position
where a.outcome = TRUE)
```

however I would rather avoid having to create a table and deleting records. I would rather want to just select the records I want in the first instance.

Comment: I don't see how your explanation matches the results.

Comment: Hi Gordon - basically where the id and position are the same in two different records, a FALSE value in the outcome column needs to override a record which has a TRUE value. So really I would like to only select the record where outcome is FALSE, given the initial condition.

Comment: Have edited question to clarify

Comment: @Brcezepplin . . . "I would like to only select a false outcome".  And then your result set has non-false outcomes.  That is unclear to me.

Comment: only want to select a false outcome when the same id and position appear in multiple record. for example id=1 only has 1 record, so TRUE or FALSE is fine here. The last record has id=2 (so same as 2nd and 3rd record), but the position=02, so it is fine to be TRUE or FALSE also. however because records 2 and 3 both share the same id and position, i only want to select the record with the false outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get only one output row for each unique combination of the `id`/`position` columns, use grouping over those columns.
To prioritize the FALSE value, just get the smallest value in the group:

```
SELECT id,
       min(outcome) AS outcome,
       position
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY id, position;
```

Comment: thank you. very simple - kicking myself for not thinking of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM   Yourtable a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Yourtable  b
                   WHERE  a.id = b.id
                          AND a.position = b.position
                          AND a.outcome > b.outcome)
```

In alphabetical ordering `FALSE` will be ordered before `TRUE`. So only `FALSE` records will be returned when there is both `TRUE` and `FALSE` for a particular `id` and `position combination

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `select`.  Something like this:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where outcome = FALSE or (id = position);
```

I don't quite follow the rules that you really want.

You can put this into a view, so you can access the results you want as if it were a table:

```
create view myview as
    select t.*
    from mytable t
    where outcome = FALSE or (id = position);
```